# Home Button and Back to Same Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-homebutton

I have an application that starts with a login screen and the goes to a gridview and continues the flow. When the user presses the Home Button I want to do something in such a way that when he starts [clicks in the .apk again] the application restores his PHP session id, identifying that he was logged, and goes straight to this other activity that manages the gridview...

In few words: the user press home button and when start the application again he is already logged in and goes directly to the activity he was...

Comment: Isn't this a default behaviour? Android maintains activity stack for your app and should return back to the same activity where you was before going to Home.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) which explains the different available data-storage mechanism in android.

For your problem the answer is [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). You save a preference and when the user restarts you can check for the preference value and do whatever is needed.

Comment: Complicated... i was reading about this...
"This behavior happens when you start your application from Eclipse, from command line or if you install an application and press on the Open button(instead of the Done button) to start the application right after you installed it."

And it is true... the problem just happens if you open the application after installing it. Instead, if you click on DONE and open the application through the menu, it does not present any problem...

What i did not find was an explanation for this... why by clicking directly in OPEN after install the problem happens...